# Graphing average using crossfilter and dc.js

Tags: javascript, reduce, dc.js, linechart, crossfilter

I'm trying to plot average on a line graph where the x axis is the month and the y-axis is the capacity. Here is an example of the data I'm trying to graph:

```
{month : "1", capacity: "48"}
{month : "1", capacity: "60"}
{month : "2", capacity: "67"}
{month : "2", capacity: "60"}
{month : "3", capacity: "66"}
{month : "3", capacity: "52"}
{month : "4", capacity: "63"}
{month : "4", capacity: "67"}
{month : "5", capacity: "80"}
{month : "5", capacity: "61"}
{month : "5", capacity: "66"}
{month : "6", capacity: "54"}
{month : "6", capacity: "69"}
```

So I'm trying to take the average capacity for each week. For some reason when I am trying to plot it using dc, the line isn't showing up. I see the numbers on the x and y axis, but the graph is blank.

Here is my code, any assistance will be appreciate it

```
let chart = dc.lineChart("#chart");
let ndx = crossfilter(<example data from above>);
            
let monthDimension = ndx.dimension(function (d) {
     return d.month;
});

function reduceAdd(p, v) {
    ++p.count;
    p.total += v.capacity;
    p.average = p.total / p.count;
    return p;
}

function reduceRemove(p, v) {
    --p.count;
    p.total -= v.capacity;
    p.average = p.count ? p.total / p.count : 0;
    return p;
}

function reduceInitial() {
    return { count: 0, total: 0, average: 0 };
} 

let capacityGroup = monthDimension.group().reduce(reduceAdd, reduceRemove, reduceInitial);
            
chart.width(360)
    .height(200)
    .margins({ top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 50, left: 30 })
    .mouseZoomable(false)
    .x(d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 52]))
    .renderHorizontalGridLines(true)
    .brushOn(false)
    .dimension(weekDimension)
    .valueAccessor(function (d) {
        return d.value.average;
    })
    .group(capacityGroup );

dc.renderAll('chart');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, the dreaded "blank chart". We've all faced that.

Luckily there were a couple of errors in the browser console that show part of the way. Then there were a couple of changes I guess you just have to learn by experience.

I made the following changes and got a chart which looks correct.

1. `dc.renderAll()` does not normally take a parameter, unless you have multiple chart groups (usu. multiple instances of crossfilter).
2. `d3.scale.linear()` is D3@3 syntax; I changed it to `d3.scaleLinear()` for D3@6. Up to you which version you want to use, however you will need to use dc@2 if you want to use D3@3.
3. `weekDimension` was not defined; I changed it to `monthDimension` for your data.
4. (The most subtle change.) Your input data is strings, which will not be converted automatically to numbers. If you try to "add" strings they will concatenate and you will get big numbers and weird results.

So I added this loop at the top, to convert the strings to numbers:

```
data.forEach(d => {
  d.month = +d.month;
  d.capacity = +d.capacity;
})
```

It's also possible to convert on the fly, but I think it's more efficient and robust to do it up-front.

[image: chart screenshot]

[Fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/19u7yc5e/11/).

Comment: You are a LIFE SAVER! Converting strings to numbers made it work perfectly. Thank you so much!